# I am getting Name Error in else statement

Tags: python

So! I made a simple program that gets a file name as input and open it and read it.
and there is a special file name "mbox.txt", to open it user must insert the pin code, after that user can access the content of the file.

for this I made a if else condition, if fname=="mbox.txt":
insert pass
else:
open it normally,

and yes! I use try,except and finally, if the file does not find execute runs the except code otherwise  continue with finally.

when ever I insert unknown file name it runs the except code and gives the NameError.

```
fname=input("Enter the file name: ")
try:
   open_file=open(fname)
except:
 print("The File'",fname,"'Did not find Please Enter A Existing File")
finally:
   y=3
if fname=="mbox.txt": 
  while y>0:
    print("To Open This File You Need To Insert The Access Passward")
    line=int(input("Insert passward"))
    if line==8523:
       read= open_file.read()
       print(read)  
       break
    else:
        if y==3 :
            print("Access Denied!")           
            y=y-1
            continue
        elif y==2:
           print("Access Denied!")   
           y=y-1
           continue
        else:
           print("UNKNOWN USER DETECTED, THE PROGRAM TERMINATE IMMIDIATELY")   
           break
         
else:
 read= open_file.read()
 print(read)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\TRED WINGS\Desktop\py\tempCodeRunnerFile.py", line 30, in <module>
    read= open_file.read()
NameError: name 'open_file' is not defined
```

Comment: The code won't start running from the top again when you hit the exception, so if you want to keep asking until the user provides a valid file name, you'll need to wrap it in a `while` loop for example

Comment: Please pay attention to proper formatting, it makes your code easier to read, understand and get right. Also, extract a [mcve] to help you understand the core of the problem. Search for the error message, too. As a new user here, also read [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I think what happens is: 1) `try: open_file=open(fname)` 2) this raises an exception 3) `except: print(...)` 4) `if fname=="mbox.txt": #no else: read= open_file.read()` 5) this errors because `open_file` was not defined successfully (exception raised in step 2)

Comment: the main bulk of your code should be in an `else:` branch of the `try/except` structure, so that it only executes if no exception was raised

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some control flow suggestions. I am making some guesses:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python


MAX_ATTEMPTS = 3
attempts = 0

while True:
    fname = input("Enter the file name: ")
    try:
        open_file = open(fname)
        break
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"{fname} could not be found, please enter a file that exists.")


if fname == "mbox.txt":
    print("To Open This File You Need To Insert The Access Password")

    while MAX_ATTEMPTS > 0:
        line = input("Insert password (numbers only): ")


        if not line.isdigit():
            print("Invalid password, must pass digits, e.g. 2388")

            # Uncomment next line to count invalid entries against attempts:
            # attempts += 1

            continue
        
        if int(line) == 8523:
            read = open_file.read()
            print(read)

            break
        if attempts >= MAX_ATTEMPTS:
            print("UNKNOWN USER DETECTED, THE PROGRAM TERMINATE IMMIDIATELY")

            break
        else:
            attempts += 1

            print("Access Denied!")
else:
    read = open_file.read()
    print(read)
```

File entry:

- Wrap the file entry in a `while True` loop to continue until it finds an existing file.
- Use `try` / `catch` pattern wrapping [`open(file, mode='r')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) and catching [`FileNotFoundError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#FileNotFoundError)

Attempts:

- Use constant (all upper case) for max attempts
- Set `attempts` to 0
- Optionally added a type check to make sure numbers/digits are entered

  Uncomment `attempts += 1` if you want invalid entries to count toward retries
- In the `if` condition, check for exhausting the max number of retries first
- Remove `continue` unless its needed to skip the rest of the loops (if it's the last line in the loop's block, it a noop)

Comment: i think I got my answere but it's not accepting the correct pin

Comment: input returns a string.  need to check `if int(line) == correct_pin`

Comment: @Kurt Updated, good catch. Does that work better @Yasir?